# Should I use matrix[][max] or **matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I think it will be very easy when I do it with this:

```
int n = 4;
int matrix[n][n];
```

rather then:

```
p = new int *[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   p[i] = new int [n];
```

So, Which is better? When do we use ** to create a matrix or a array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int n = 4;
> int matrix[n][n];
> ```

Your first example isn't c++ standard conform, the standard doesn't support variable length arrays.

> ```
> int** p = new int *[n];
>
> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
>      p[i] = new int [n];
> ```

For your second example you should better use a `std::vector<int>` instead and organize matrix rows and columns as sections in the vector:

```
int n = 4;
std::vector<int> matrix(n*n);
```

Using `new` and `delete` yourself is usually not necessary in C++ and peppered with pitfalls and obstacles, which are taken care of in the appropriate standard library container and smart pointer classes.

Answer (score 1):

First declaration is non-standard: `n` must be known at compile time in order for the code to compile. Some compilers offer variable-length arrays as an extension, but the code remains non-standard.

The standard approach to situations when you need a matrix in C++ is to use `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` for situations when the size is *not* known until the runtime. When the size is known at compile time and you prefer allocation in automatic area, use `std::array<N,std::array<N,T>>` instead of vectors.

Both these approaches let you construct objects that behave exactly like arrays of arrays, but you don't need to manage their memory explicitly.